os.system multiple return values
Is it possible to get multiple return values for a os.system() call?
The following example always returns 0 even though the python call returns an error code
ret_val = os.system(f"python3 -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)' | tee test.log")

The goal is to get a list of return values, in this case:
ret_val == [1, 0]


That's because tee returns (exits with) 0


Is it possible to get multiple return values for a os.system() call?

No. os.system starts one process - the shell, and the shell exits with one exit code.
A pipeline | is a shell construct. The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the rightmost command. These are the rules of shell language. They have nothing to do with python or os.system.
You can:

write the pipeline in python
use Bash shell with PIPESTATUS variable and extract that

Additionally, prefer subprocess module over os.system.

For reference, to run the pipeline in python, you would:
with subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python3 -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)'"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as ouf:
   with subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("tee test.log"), stdin=outf.stdout) as inf:
      outf.wait()
      inf.wait()
ret_val = [outf.returncode, inf.returncode]

But this tee is just useless, it's easy to do in python:
with open("test.log") as f:
   subprocess.run(shlex.split("python3 -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)'"), stdout=f, check=True)
   

To use Bash PIPESTATUS you have to run Bash specifically and write a Bash shell script, that utilizes some form of interprocess communication, to communicate the values of PIPESTATUS back to python. Typically, for interprocess communication a normal file is used for nonblocking simple communication:
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("rt") as f:
    subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", """
        python3 -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)' | tee test.log
        echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" > "$1"
        """, "bash", f.name], check=True)
    ret_val = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]

